# MySql Connector enviando valor nulo

Tags: c#, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
MySqlConnection mysql = new MySqlConnection(CONEXAO);
mysql.Open();
try
{
    MySqlCommand dbcmd = mysql.CreateCommand();
    dbcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO robos (id,nome,cabelo,olhos,bracos,boca,cabeca,pernas,corpo) VALUES (@id,@nome,@cabelo,@olhos,@bracos,@boca,@cabeca,@pernas,@corpo); ";
    this.ativo = new Robo();
    this.ativo.Nome = this.nome.Text;
    this.ativo.Cabelo = new Cor(this.cabelo.SelectedItem.ToString(), this.defineCor(this.cabelo.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    this.ativo.Cabeca = new Cor(this.cabeca.SelectedItem.ToString(), this.defineCor(this.cabeca.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    this.ativo.Olho = new Cor(this.olhos.SelectedItem.ToString(), this.defineCor(this.olhos.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    this.ativo.Boca = new Cor(this.boca.SelectedItem.ToString(), this.defineCor(this.boca.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    this.ativo.Braco = new Cor(this.bracos.SelectedItem.ToString(), this.defineCor(this.bracos.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    this.ativo.Corpo = new Cor(this.corpo.SelectedItem.ToString(), this.defineCor(this.corpo.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    this.ativo.Perna = new Cor(this.pernas.SelectedItem.ToString(), this.defineCor(this.pernas.SelectedItem.ToString()));

    Console.WriteLine(
        "Id: " + ativo.Id + "\n" +
        "nome: " + ativo.Nome + "\n" +
        "Cabelo: " + ativo.Cabelo.Nome.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Cabeca: " + ativo.Cabeca.Nome.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Olho: " + ativo.Olho.Nome.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Boca: " + ativo.Boca.Nome.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Corpo: " + ativo.Corpo.Nome.ToString() + "\n" +
        "Perna: " + ativo.Perna.Nome.ToString() + "\n"
        );

    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ativo.Id);
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", ativo.Nome.ToString());
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cabelo", ativo.Cabelo.Nome.ToString());
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@olhos", ativo.Olho.Nome.ToString());
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bracos", ativo.Braco.Nome.ToString());
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@boca", ativo.Boca.Nome.ToString());
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cabeca", ativo.Cabeca.Nome.ToString());
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pernas", ativo.Perna.Nome.ToString());
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corpo", ativo.Corpo.Nome.ToString());
    dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    dbcmd.Dispose();
    dbcmd = null;
    mysql.Close();
    mysql = null;
    this.info.Text = "SALVOU";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.info.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

Toda hora que tento executar ele o erro retornado do mysql é que a coluna nome não aceita valor nulo, mas no próprio Console.WriteLine é exibido os valores, como exemplo:

```
nome: stack
Cabelo: Preto
Cabeca: Branco
Olho: Rosa
Boca: Rosa
Corpo: Azul
Perna: Amarelo
```

Estou usando o MySql Connector 5.0, pois o banco de dados é o MySql 3, daí esse é o connector mais recente compatível.

Alguém sabe o que poderia está dando errado? o `SELECT * FROM robos` está funcionando de boa.

Segue o Stack Trace:

```
----------------STACK----------


   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.OpenPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadResult(UInt64& affectedRows, Int64& lastInsertId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetResultSet()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Fabrica.Form1.save() in C:\Documents and Settings\Leonardo\Meus documentos\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\FeiraDeCarro\FeiraDeCarro\Form1.cs:line 201



---------------- FIM STACK----------
```

Onde a linha 201 é : `dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Uma dúvida: por que usar `.ToString()` em strings?

Comment: Por favor coloque o *stack trace* completo na pergunta. Qual o tipo da coluna `nome`? `Id` não é identity insert?

Comment: @jbueno, o `ToString()` foi só uma tentativa, porque num sei mais o que fazer rs.. Vou colocar

Comment: Não faz sentido usar `ToString` numa `string`. O problema está noutro lugar. Se você tentar passar um valor *hardcoded* funciona?

Comment: Realmente não faz sentido, mas nos tempos do `C` ocorria alguns bugs assim, daí tento de tudo. Tentei com valores fixos, também não funciona.

Comment: O ideal seria você verificar quais campos da tabela robos não aceitam valores NULL, e verificar na aplicação o que você esta passando nesses campos, veja se esta especificando todos os campos da tabela também...    como foi especificado também, não use o (id, no insert se seu campo e auto_increment .

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod todos campos são NOT NULL, nem passando parâmetros fixos para o `MySqlCommand` está funcionando, todas as colunas da tabela estão na query, e nem retirando o ID funcionou. A única maneira que testei agora e funcionou é do jeito 'porco' de ir concatenando string e criando a query.

Answer (score 0):

Seu `id` é chave primária e auto increment? se for auto increment, não pode ser colocada no `insert`.

Edit: fiz o seguinte: [image: Banco robo]

com o seguinte código:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var CONEXAO = "Server=localhost;Database=robo;Uid=root;Pwd="; //Aqui você substitui pelos seus dados

    MySqlConnection mysql = new MySqlConnection(CONEXAO);
    mysql.Open();
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand dbcmd = mysql.CreateCommand();
        dbcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO robos (id,nome,cabelo,olhos,bracos,boca,cabeca,pernas,corpo) VALUES (@id,@nome,@cabelo,@olhos,@bracos,@boca,@cabeca,@pernas,@corpo); ";

        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", "Gabriel");
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cabelo", "Preto");
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@olhos", "Azul");
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bracos", "2 braços");
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@boca", "1 boca");
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cabeca", "1 cabeça");
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pernas", "2 pernas");
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corpo", "body");
        dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        dbcmd.Dispose();
        dbcmd = null;
        mysql.Close();
        mysql = null;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

E funcionou.

Obs.:

- Versão do MySQL: 5.7.14
- Última versão do MySQLConnector.

Comment: Sim, está como auto_increment

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza absoluta se é este o problema, mas eu já tive problemas no C# ao colocar o Id para salvar, em uma chave com auto_increment.

Comment: Já tentei tirando o ID também e não rolou, o problema está a partir do nome.

Comment: Legal você querer ajudar, mas você usou o campo de resposta para fazer um comentário. Você poderá postar comentários quando tiver [um pouco mais de pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor utilize o campo de resposta somente para postar uma solução ao problema de que a pergunta trata.